# Not to beat a dead horse: running five "Hello World" java apps uses 700MB of RAM

Tags: java, memory

I've been struggling with memory usage on this server, but I think I've finally found a minimal case:

```
public class Hello {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Throwable {
            System.out.println("HI");
            Thread.sleep(3600 * 1000);
            return;
    }
}
```

Running five copies of this application uses a total of 700MB of RAM. And this is after I modify the command line to:

```
java -client -Xmx6m -Xbatch -XX:MaxPermSize=2m Hello
```

(I've tried with `-server` instead, to no effect. `-Xbatch` is for giggles, it doesn't change the memory usage.)

My theory is somehow the JVMs aren't sharing between themselves.

Data from VisualVM:

```
820KM heap (after GC); 8.4MB PermGen; 1136 classes loaded.
```

JVM info:

```
root@devel:~# java -version
java version "1.6.0_22"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_22-b04)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 17.1-b03, mixed mode)
```

Ubuntu 10.04 LTE server.

That seems pretty high, and basically prevents me from running more than two java applications at the same time.

Any ideas what might be going wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: Ah, right. Sorry. Edited. The question is how to lower the memory usage, because right now I can't run more than two java applications on that server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure you are running a Java 1.6 virtual machine? Because it seems that class data memory sharing has been there since 1.5...

https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=4416624

Copying from comments:

Class data sharing is supported only for 32bit JVM and client HotSpot. This 'Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM' shows that you are running 64bit JVM. So download 32bit version and try: java -d32 -client -version you should get: java version "1.6.0_22" Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_22-b04) Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 17.1-b03, mixed mode, sharing) note the 'Client VM' and 'sharing' above. – Tomas Hurka

Comment: root@devel:/app/axir/target# java -version
java version "1.6.0_22"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_22-b04)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 17.1-b03, mixed mode)

Comment: root@devel:/app/axir/target# java -Xshare:on -version
Class data sharing is inconsistent with other specified options.
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Unable to use shared archive.

Comment: Curiously. If I try this on a Mac, supposedly also running 1.6.0_22 I get a different message: 


[wiktor ~]#java -Xshare:on -version
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Shared archive is not supported on the Server JVM.

Comment: Hmmm... Then I guess you could have better chances of getting a solution in superuser or serverfault, because the problem might be on the host operating system (maybe some selinux policy preventing memory sharing unless explicitly enabled? I don't know :-/)

Comment: That's a good idea. I'll try that, thank you. I'm seriously considering just switching hosts at the moment, might be the easiest fix since this seems to be a pretty arcane failure mode.

Comment: also the post I linked seems to be pretty extensive, maybe there's something more interesting to read in it

Comment: Class data sharing is supported only for 32bit JVM and client HotSpot. This 'Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM' shows that you are running 64bit JVM. So download 32bit version and try:
java -d32 -client -version
you should get:
java version "1.6.0_22"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_22-b04)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 17.1-b03, mixed mode, sharing)

note the 'Client VM' and 'sharing' above.

Comment: @Tomas Hurka I will update the answer with your very clarifying comment :-)

Comment: @Tomas Hurka: Ah. I installed a 32 bit JVM and tried enabling class sharing, and the memory usage doubled.... I have to admit I was too lazy to keep investigating and I simply switched hosts and the problem went away. Using a normal 64bit JVM the memory usage is only ~60MB. Thank you for your help. I'm not sure what was misconfigured, but it was the same JVM from the same repository, so it seems to be some OS-level thing.